# Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement debug android app

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying to debug my app to see where it stops running, but I'm confused with the following log "Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@42088f90" I don't know what it means or where it's coming from.

```
07-01 13:55:30.957  11534-11534/com.rep I/RM﹕ construct
07-01 13:55:30.957  11534-11534/com.rep I/RM﹕ onPreExecute
07-01 13:55:30.961  11534-12159/com.rep I/RM﹕ doInBackground
07-01 13:55:30.961  11534-12159/com.rep I/RM﹕ URL DE CONSULTA: http://192.168.1.1/rep/api/clientes
01 13:55:30.962  11534-12159/com.rep I/RM﹕ [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@42088f90
```

This is the code:

```
package com.rep.webservice.rest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.rep.model.ClienteModel;
import com.rep.webservice.Servidor;
import com.rep.webservice.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.rep.webservice.volley.Request;
import com.rep.webservice.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.rep.webservice.volley.Response;
import com.rep.webservice.volley.VolleyError;
import com.rep.webservice.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.rep.webservice.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.lang.String.valueOf;

public class ClientesRest extends Servidor {

    private String recursoRest = "clientes";

    private List arrayClientes;

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private Context context;

    public ClientesRest(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    public final List getClientes() {

        String url = this.URL_WS + recursoRest;

        Log.i("RM", "URL DE CONSULTA: " + url);


        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context);



        JsonObjectRequest mJsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                parseJSON(response);

                Log.i("RM", "resposta da api: " + response.toString());


            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("RM", error.getMessage());
            }

        }
        ) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("X-TOKEN", "99KI9Gj68CgCf70deM22Ka64chef2Caaa2J0G9JkD0bDAcbFfd19MfacGf3FFm8CM1hG0eDiIk8");
                return headers;
            }
        };

        mRequestQueue.add(mJsonObjectRequest);


        return this.arrayClientes;
    }

    private void parseJSON(JSONObject json) {
        try {

            Log.i("RM", "executou o parseJSON");

            /* array para armazenar os clientes */
            this.arrayClientes = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();

            /* pega o array "dados" que vem na resposta da consulta ao rest */
            JSONArray dados = json.getJSONArray("dados");

            /* percorre o array */
            for (int i = 0; i < dados.length(); i++) {

                /* pega a posição de cada linha no array */
                JSONObject item = dados.getJSONObject(i);

                /* cria um objeto do tipo ClienteModel */
                ClienteModel mClienteModel = new ClienteModel();

                /* cadastra os dados necessários no objeto mClienteModel */
                mClienteModel.set_idrm(Integer.parseInt(item.optString("id")));
                mClienteModel.set_nome(item.optString("nome"));
                mClienteModel.set_tipo(item.getString("tipo"));
                mClienteModel.set_endereco(item.optString("endereco"));
                mClienteModel.set_numero(item.optString("numero"));
                mClienteModel.set_complemento(item.optString("complemento"));
                mClienteModel.set_cep(item.optString("cep"));
                mClienteModel.set_bairro(item.optString("bairro"));
                mClienteModel.set_cidade(item.optString("cidade"));
                mClienteModel.set_estado(item.optString("estado"));
                mClienteModel.set_informacao_adicional("informacao_adicional");

                /* adicionar o objeto mClienteModel no array de Clientes "arrayClientes" */
                this.arrayClientes.add(mClienteModel);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: try printing stackTrace of "error" , error.printStackTrace(). Considering volleyerror extends exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the default `.toString()` of `StackTraceElement` class.

You should use it's methods to print the stacktrace, or better, use the `Log` argument which is used to print stacktraces in the logcat.

```
Log.i("RM", "error", error);
```

Comment: thank you, Now the log says - java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.rep.webservice.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:45)